# How to mask a fragment shader

Tags: android, opengl-es, camera, fragment-shader

I want to implement backround blurring for selfie camera.
I have a blurring fragment shader

```c
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D uSampler;
uniform float uBlur;
uniform float uRadius;

varying vec2 vTextureCoord;

void main() {
  vec3 sum = vec3(0);
  if (uBlur > 0.0) {
    for (float i = -uBlur; i < uBlur; i++) {
      for (float j = -uBlur; j < uBlur; j++) {
        sum += texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord + vec2(i, j) * (uRadius / uBlur)).rgb / pow(uBlur * 2.0, 2.0);
      }
    }
  } else {
    sum = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord).rgb;
  }
  gl_FragColor = vec4(sum, 1.0);
}
```

Also I have an array which indicates where I need to put blurring effect.
My idea is to pass the array somehow to the fragment shader and skip coordinates that should not be blurred.
Is there any way to do that or is there any other way I should follow?

**UPD0:**
Mask is generated dynamically several times per second. The mask data contained by `com.google.mlkit.vision.segmentation.SegmentationMask` class -  It has `ByteBuffer` with `width` and `heigh` inside.
I tried to generate a bitmap with
`Bitmap.createBitmap(maskColorsFromByteBuffer(mask), maskWidth, maskHeight, Config.ARGB_8888)`
and

```java
    private int[] maskColorsFromByteBuffer(ByteBuffer byteBuffer) {
        @ColorInt int[] colors = new int[maskWidth * maskHeight];
        for (int i = 0; i < maskWidth * maskHeight; i++) {
            float backgroundLikelihood = 1 - byteBuffer.getFloat();
            if (backgroundLikelihood > 0.9) {
                colors[i] = Color.argb(128, 51, 112, 69);
            } else if (backgroundLikelihood > 0.2) {
                // Linear interpolation to make sure when backgroundLikelihood is 0.2, the alpha is 0 and
                // when backgroundLikelihood is 0.9, the alpha is 128.
                // +0.5 to round the float value to the nearest int.
                int alpha = (int) (182.9 * backgroundLikelihood - 36.6 + 0.5);
                colors[i] = Color.argb(alpha, 51, 112, 69);
            }
        }
        return colors;
    }
```

After generating the bitmap I tried to draw it with [ImageObjectFilterRender](https://github.com/pedroSG94/rtmp-rtsp-stream-client-java/blob/4b85bce8475deb97380dad3bbe51aca6d24087ea/encoder/src/main/java/com/pedro/encoder/input/gl/render/filters/object/ImageObjectFilterRender.java)  - as far as I see that class generating texture from the bitmap.

Comment: Why not store the mask in a texture?

Comment: How that should work? Mask is the dinamyc thing which changes about 4 times during the second. I have tried to build a bitmap from it and use `ImageObjectFilterRender` class from here https://github.com/pedroSG94/rtmp-rtsp-stream-client-java, but it lags too mach

Comment: *"Mask is the dynamic thing which changes about 4 times"* -this is a new information. However it doesn't change anything. The usual way to do this is with a texture, UB or SSBO. How do you generate the mask data? Can you render it to a texture.

Comment: Please see UPD0 in the description.

Comment: I see . So load the mask data (`color`) to a texture. Create the texture with [`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) (once) and update the image data with [`glTexSubImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glTexSubImage2D.xhtml) (after the mask has been changed).